# realm command doesn't work correctly when used in script (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, active-directory

I try to automate the authentication on CentOS 7 Hosts over my AD with the realm commands.

It totally works when I execute the following commands by myself.

```
$ yum -y install realmd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir sssd samba-common
$ realm join -U admin domain.com
$ realm permit -g LinuxAdmins@domain.com
```

In addition to that I replace the following lines in */etc/sssd/sssd.conf* and restart sssd service.

```
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u

$systemctl restart sssd
```

After those steps I can log in on that specific CentOS Host with any permitted user of my Active Directory

**Now the Problem:**

If I run the following script on a CentOS Host as root it seems like everything has worked.

```
 yum -y install realmd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir sssd samba-common
 echo "Password" | realm join -U admin domain.com
 realm permit -g LinuxAdmins@domain.com
 sed -i -e 's/use_fully_qualified_names = True/use_fully_qualified_names = False/g' /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
 sed -i -e 's#fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d#fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u#g' /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
 systemctl restart sssd
```

If I try to log in as a permitted AD user it says *permission denied*

I checked */etc/sssd/sssd.conf* for any possible sed-caused problems, but that seems fine. Also running the command *realm list* seems like there is no problem.

```
# realm list
domain.com
type: kerberos
realm-name: DOMAIN.COM
domain-name: domain.com
configured: kerberos-member
server-software: active-directory
client-software: sssd
required-package: oddjob
required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
required-package: sssd
required-package: adcli
required-package: samba-common
login-formats: %U
login-policy: allow-permitted-logins
permitted-logins:
permitted-groups: LinuxAdmins@domain.com
```

The output of this command is exactly the same when I run it after manually executing the commands.

Anybody any idea how to handle that?

Comment: No winbind or like restart ?

Comment: @Archemar I restarted the system but that doesn't help either

Comment: the only diff is `echo "Passwd" | realm ` are you sure this is allowed ? are there no other option to give password ?

Comment: @Archemar yes it works when I run that in command line as root

Comment: Can you please post the output of `id [ASUSER]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I noticed that `ldap_id_mapping = True` was my solution. This is in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include verbose output of the realm join command. The way you are using echo to pipe the password to the realm command is the right way to script it.
Here is what I use:

```
echo $passwd | realm join --verbose --membership-software=adcli  --user=administrator MYDOMAIN.COM
```

I also allowed the groups using different formatting. This is the way that works for me.

```
realm permit --groups "mydomain.com\\group-name"
```

In my sssd.conf I have

```
[domain/mydomain.com]
ad_domain = mydomain.com
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
ad_maximum_machine_account_password_age = 0
ldap_sasl_mech = GSS-SPNEGO
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = mydomain.com\group-name
```